# Virtual list (Problems with parameter/pointer)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to convert my CListCtrl into a virtual list, but i dont know which parameter i have to use

```
    // --- Virtual List ---
void CSpielebibliothekGUIDlg::OnGetdispinfoList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) // --- nullptr muss weg --- 
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMIA = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);

    LV_DISPINFO* pDispInfo = (LV_DISPINFO*)pNMHDR;

    LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;

    int itemid = pItem->iItem;

    if (pItem->mask & LVIF_TEXT)
    {
        CString text;
        // --- Welche Spalte ---
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 0)
        {
            // --- Name ---
            text = Spiele[itemid].m_Name;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 1)
        {
            //Text is slogan
            text = Spiele[itemid].m_Plattform;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 2)
        {
            text = Spiele[itemid].m_Genre;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 3)
        {
            CString Release;
            Release.Format(_T("%d"), Spiele[itemid].m_Erscheinungsjahr);
            text = Release;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 4)
        {
            CString Preis;
            Preis.Format(_T("%g"), Spiele[itemid].m_Preis);
            text = Preis;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 5)
        {
            CString EAN;
            EAN.Format(_T("%d"), Spiele[itemid].m_EAN);
            text = EAN;
        }
        if (pItem->iSubItem == 6)
        {
            text = Spiele[itemid].Verwandschaft;
        }

        lstrcpyn(pItem->pszText, text, pItem->cchTextMax);
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

this is my function call

```
    OnGetdispinfoList(nullptr, nullptr);
```

of course the nullptr are not right, iam glad for any help.

Comment: As always, the MFC documentation is far less helpful than the Windows API documentation. [Virtual List-View Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) explains the basics, while [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) offers complete sample code. Being able to translate Windows API code to MFC code is a required skill for any MFC developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call message handlers, they will be called by system after you:

- Set proper window styles (LVS_OWNERDATA)
- Set item count
- Add your `OnGetdispinfoList` to the message map

Comment: So, you mean i dont have to use this part...?
    OnGetdispinfoList(nullptr, nullptr);

Comment: @Miyutic, yes, you call [CListCtrl::SetItemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-170#setitemcount) and the message handler is called from the message map.